# Can you cast Hangarback Walker for X=0 and have it survive with Hardened Scales?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm building a deck with [Hangarback Walker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hangarback%20Walker) and [Hardened Scales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hardened%20Scales), and I was wondering if I could cast Hangarback for X=0, and it would activate Hardened Scales. Just a thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, and for a very straightforward reason: Hardened Scales requires that *at least* one counter be placed on the creature before it adds any additional counters:

[image: Hardened Scales]

The key text here is 'If *one or more*'.  You're trying to put zero counters on the Hangarback Walker, and so Hardened Scales never processes.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, I guess I wasn't paying attention to the full ability.

Answer (score 5):

Casting [Hangarback Walker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hangarback%20Walker) for 0, and it will enter the battlefield with zero +1/+1 counters. Since [Hardened Scales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hardened%20Scales) requires "one or more" +1/+1 counters to be put on the permanent to trigger the replacement effect, [Hardened Scales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hardened%20Scales) won't trigger. [Hangarback Walker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hangarback%20Walker) will Enter the Battlefield as a 0/0, and die due to state based Actions.

If you want to play [Hangarback Walker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hangarback%20Walker) for free, there are options:

1. Have a permanent in play that provides an anthem effect to your creatures of at least +0/+1.
2. Have it enter with a +1/+1 counter for Free. [Zameck Guildmage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zameck%20Guildmage) or [Master Biomancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Master%20Biomancer).

Graft is not an option. Though the triggered effect of the creature will happen, state based actions will kill the 0/0 [Hangarback Walker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hangarback%20Walker) before the trigger can be placed on the stack.

Comment: While relevant, this is tangential and not actually answering the question.

Comment: Actually, he answered the question and then provided additional relevant "tangential" information.  Nothing wrong with that.  Going on a tangent myself, the answer wasn't any different than the preceding answer and the additional info should, IMHO, just have been added as a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: The answer was initially solely tangential, to provide the effect desired by the Question. It was than edited to address the specific question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to add to Steven Stadnicki's answer that even if it was a triggered ability that put counters on creatures when they enter the battlefield it still will not work.

State base actions would see a creature with zero toughness and it would be put in the graveyard before the triggered ability gets a chance to put any counters on it.

So lets say for instance instead of the scales you had [Aquastrand Spider](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397697) it still would not work for the reason I stated.

Comment: This is tangential, and doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Ability is triggered, but it isn't put on the stack.

Comment: Notice that Hardened Scales effect is not a triggered ability but a static replacement effect.